No continuous functions such that $f(g(x)+h(y))=xy$

Show that there exist no continuous functions $f,g,h:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(g(x)+h(y))=xy$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}.$

I haven't been able to make much progress on this question. I have shown that if such functions exist, then none of them can be constant. One can put $y=0$ to get that $f(g(x)+h(0))=0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}.$ Similarly, $f(g(0)+h(y))=0$ for all $y\in\mathbb{R}.$ So, $f$ is $0$ on $g(0)+\textrm{range}(h)$ and $h(0)+\textrm{range}(g).$
I don't know where to go from here. Clearly, we need to use continuity somewhere. I tried to find sequences along which the functional equation would give a contradiction, but that didn't work.

Notice that f(g(1)+h(x))=x so f is injective thus strictly monotonous since continuous, this means that h=0 and g=0

@julio_es_sui_glace, wait, how does that show that $f$ is injective? I am not clear as to how $h=g=0$ follows either.

Sorry my mistake it is surjective so forget what I said but h and g are definitely injective so strictly monotonuous maybe you can reach a contradiction

@julio_es_sui_glace, yes $f$ is surjective. And, I can see why $g$ and $h$ are injective, and hence strictly monotonic (by continuity).

Doesn’t it mean that necessarily range (g) = R otherwise f would be discontinuous if it was bounded under or over

@julio_es_sui_glace $\arctan x$ is bounded, injective, strictly increasing and continuous.

Explore limits with the extrem "bounds."

@geetha290krm arctan des not satisfy the properties here... I did not write a full answer since it is the comments

@julio_es_sui_glace Yes, but the question is how you are jumping to the conclusion that $g$ has to be surjective.

@geetha290krm I'll admit it was quick but I wrote it down

$\exp(\ln(x) + \ln(y)) = xy$, but we all know that $\ln(x)$ is not continuous in $0$. Is that the source of your question?

@Dominique, not sure about where the question is originally from. A friend gave it to me, and he told me it was on an undergraduate real analysis exam.

$\newcommand{\range}{\text{range}}$ Note that \begin{equation}f(g(y) +h(1)) = y\tag{1}\end{equation} for all $y \in \mathbb R$, so $\mathbb R = \range(f)$.

Note that $g$ and $h$ are injective : if $g(x)=g(y)$, then $g(x)+h(1)= g(y)+h(1)$, then $f(g(x)+h(1)) = f(g(y)+h(1))$, which gives $x=y$. A similar argument holds for $h$.
In particular, since $g,h$ are injective continuous functions, they are strictly monotone and their ranges are intervals.

Suppose that $g$ is a bounded function. Then, there exists $N>0$ such that $$\range(g) \subset [-N,N].$$ This implies that $$\{g(x) + h(1) : x \in \mathbb R\} \subset [-N+h(1) , N+h(1)].$$ Now, since $f$ is continuous, it maps the compact interval $[-N+h(1),N+h(1)]$ to a compact, hence bounded interval.
This contradicts the implication of $(1)$, which would be that $f$ maps $[-N+h(1),N+h(1)]$ surjectively onto the unbounded set $\mathbb R$.
Hence, the range of $g$ is unbounded.

Let $z,z' \in \mathbb R$ be such that $h(0), h(z')$ and $h(z)$ are all different (this is possible since $h$ is injective). Since $g$ is an unbounded monotonic function, its range extends infinitely either towards $+\infty$ or towards $-\infty$.
In either case, one can find $M$ (which would be arbitrarily small or large depending upon what direction the range of $g$ is unbounded in) such that $$M-h(0),M-h(z), M-h(z') \in \range(g).$$ Suppose that $$g(x_1) = M-h(0), g(x_2) = M-h(z), g(x_3) = M-h(z').$$
Then, $$f(M)=f(g(x_1)+h(0)) = 0 \\
f(M) = f(g(x_2)+ h(z)) = x_2z \\
f(M) = f(g(x_3) + h(z')) = x_3z'
$$
This means that $x_2z = x_3z' = 0$. However, $z,z' \neq 0$, so $x_2=x_3=0$, which contradicts the fact that $g(x_2) \neq g(x_3)$.
All in all, no trio of continuous functions $f,g,h$ exist which satisfy the original equation.

The closest one can come, perhaps, to this arrangement is to look at $\exp(\ln(x)+\ln(y)) = xy$. However, this holds for all $x,y \in \mathbb R_+$ only.
Note that I crucially used the value of $h(0)$ in the last step above. This can't be used if $g,h$ have the domain $\mathbb R_+$, in which case, in fact, you wouldn't be able to find a contradiction.

Suppose everything is true.
So as you said for $x \in \operatorname{range} (g) + h(0)$, $f(x)=0$ and symmetrically for $h$.
Now you have $\operatorname{int} (\operatorname{range} (g) )= (a,b) $ since $g$ is continuous and since $f(g(x) + h(1)) = x$ we know that $g$ is injective and thus strictly monotonous so $\lim_{x\to\infty} g(x)$ exists and is in $\{a,b\}$, for simplicity we suppose it is $b$.
If $b$ is finite,
$$ \infty = \lim_{x \to \infty} x = \lim_{x \to \infty} f(g(x)+h(1)) =  \lim_{x \to b + h(1)} f(x) = f(b + h(1))$$
which is absurd and the same goes for $a$ in the case of $x\to -\infty$ which means $\operatorname{range} (g) = \mathbb{R}$, thus $f = 0$ which is absurd.

The range of $g$ may be infinite.

@EDX Yes, this is exactly my point I did not specify $a$ and $b$ to be finite

Oki donki thats alright

@EDX remove your downvote then

It isn't me actually I don't understand the downvote on your post. But I up it

@EDX ok weird then haha, I have made a small remark on your post can you correct it? and thanks for the upvote

Yes sure thanks for the remark I've corrected it.

Answer
$$f(g(x)+h(y)) =xy \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1) $$

Question : Are $g$ and/or $h$ unbounded ? Yes otherwise, i.e if both are bounded we can extract a sequence $g(x_n)\to l$ that converges in $ \mathbb{R}$ such that $x_n \to \infty$. (Bolzanno-Weistrass and fixed $y>0$). And so gives by continuity of $f$ and relation $(1)$ : $f(l)=\infty$

At least one function is so unbounded.
1st result

So $g$ or/and $h$ is/are unbounded on an interval $[a,+\infty[$ with $a<0$

Suppose without a loss of generality that $g$ is unbounded on an interval $[a, + \infty[$ and take its value in an interval $[b,+\infty[$, that so e.g. $g$, taking $y=1/x$. We know $h(0)$ exists and $f$ is continous. And $h(1/x)$ continuous on $I=[a, + \infty[ \cap [1,+\infty[$
$$ f(g(x)+h(1/x))=1, \  \ \ \forall x \in I$$ then $f$ is bounded on $[a, +\infty[$ because $g$ isn't (indeed $g$ take value in a $[b, + \infty[$)
Yet the following can grow arbitrarly grow on $I=[a, + \infty[ \cap [1,+\infty[$ which is absurd.
$$ f(g(x)+h(1/x))=x $$

You assumed $g$ and $h$ have a limit but did not prove it

I prove it now. At least for one which is sufficient

Be careful with $(x,y) \to \infty$ it means $|(x,y)| \to \infty$ in particular you have to deal with the case $(x,0)$ with $x \to \infty$ also it may be me but I don't get how you conclude that the limit exists, could you be more clear?

Maybe you can sort it out using only the fact that one of $g$ and $h$ is unbounded

Yes I correct it with unbounded argument thanks
